Trying to get Azure AI to work with Nuxt 3
For some reason, when I push this script in the server/api folder to cloudflare pages it fails every time, returning a 500 error code.When I run it with the same environment variables in development mode it works fine. Any Ideas on how to fix this?
import {getBearerTokenProvider, ClientSecretCredential } from "@azure/identity";
import { AzureOpenAI } from "openai";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig(event);
  const endpointazure = `${runtimeConfig.azureEndpoint}`;
  const keyazure = `${runtimeConfig.azureKey}`;
  const cred = new ClientSecretCredential(
    `${runtimeConfig.azureClient}`,
    `${runtimeConfig.azureTenant}`,
    `${runtimeConfig.azureSecret}`
  );
  const tokenProvider = getBearerTokenProvider(
    cred,
    "https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default"
  );
  
  interface ChatMessage {
    role: string;
    content: string;
  }
  const client = new AzureOpenAI(
    {
      tokenProvider,
      apiVersion: "2024-08-01-preview",
      endpoint: endpointazure,
      apiKey: keyazure,
    }
  );

  // Parse the request body as an object containing a 'chat' array
  const body = await readBody<{ chat: ChatMessage[] }>(event);

  // Access the 'chat' array from the body
  const chatHistory = body.chat;

  // Check if chatMessages is an array
  if (Array.isArray(chatHistory)) {
    // Iterate over each ChatMessage object and print its content
    chatHistory.forEach((message, index) => {
    });
  } else {
    console.error('Chat is not an array');
    return { error: 'Invalid chat format' };
  }

  const result = await client.chat.completions.create({
    model: 'gpt-4o-mini',
    messages: chatHistory,
    max_tokens: 150,
  });


  console.log(result.choices[0].message.content);
  return result.choices[0].message.content;
});

the result is just an internal server error 500.

Ensure all required environment variables are correctly set in Cloudflare Pages and replace ClientSecretCredential with direct apiKey usage in AzureOpenAI for compatibility.

I modified the code and directly added the endpoint, client ID, client secret, and tenant ID to the azure-openai.ts file within the server/api folder. I successfully got the output in both development and Cloudflare pages.
server/api/azure-openai.ts :
Below is the complete azure-openai.ts code
import { ClientSecretCredential } from "@azure/identity";
import { AzureOpenAI } from "openai";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  try {
    const endpointazure = "https://xxxxxxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/openai/deployments/gpt-4o-mini/chat/completions?api-version=2024-08-01-preview";
    const clientId = "<clientID>";
    const tenantId = "<tenantID>";
    const clientSecret = "<clientSecret>";

    const cred = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    const tokenResponse = await cred.getToken("https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default");
    const bearerToken = tokenResponse.token;
    const headers = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${bearerToken}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };
    const queryParams = getQuery(event);
    const chatParam = queryParams.chat;

    if (!chatParam) {
      return { error: "No chat parameter provided" };
    }
    const chatParamString = Array.isArray(chatParam) ? chatParam[0] : chatParam;
    let chatHistory;
    try {
      chatHistory = JSON.parse(chatParamString);
    } catch (err) {
      return { error: "Invalid chat format" };
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(chatHistory)) {
      return { error: "Invalid chat format" };
    }
    const response = await fetch(endpointazure, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        model: "gpt-4o-mini",
        messages: chatHistory,
        max_tokens: 150,
      }),
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      const errorResponse = await response.json();
      console.error("API Error:", errorResponse);
      return { error: "API request failed", details: errorResponse };
    }

    const result = await response.json();
    console.log("API Response:", result);
    if (result.choices && result.choices.length > 0) {
      console.log("API Response:", result.choices[0].message?.content);
      return result.choices[0].message?.content;
    } else {
      return { error: "Invalid response from OpenAI API" };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in Azure OpenAI API:", error);
    return { error: "Internal Server Error", details: (error as Error).message };
  }
});

Development Output :

I successfully deployed my Nuxt3 project to Cloudflare Pages using GitHub, as shown below.

The Cloudflare pages have been deployed successfully, as shown in the GitHub below.

CloudFlare pages Output :
I successfully got the output in the CloudFlare pages.

